# Django authenticate() always returns None

Tags: python, django, backend

I am building a web project with Django to facilitate distribution in case of an earthquake. The user needs to be a member as a Mukhtar or a Helper. The registration system works successfully. But the login part is constantly returning None value even though my login information is absolutely correct.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from base64 import b32encode
from hashlib import sha1
from random import random

# Create random id
def pkgen():
    rude = ('lol',)
    bad_pk = True
    while bad_pk:
        pk = b32encode(sha1(str(random())).digest()).lower()[:24]
        bad_pk = False
        for rw in rude:
            if pk.find(rw) >= 0: bad_pk = True
    return pk

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    muhtar = models.BooleanField(null=False,default=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=28, null=False, unique=False)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, unique=True)
    tc = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=False, unique=True)
    address = models.TextField(null=False)
    need_help = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'tc' #Uyarı! Bu benzersiz olmasını ister
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username}"

class sos(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sos_key = models.CharField(max_length=24, primary_key=True, default=pkgen, unique=True)
    address = models.TextField(null=False, unique=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}"
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "harita.html")

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("kullaniciadi")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        tc = request.POST.get("tc-no")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        muhtar = request.POST.get("muhtar-check")
        if muhtar == "on":
            muhtar = True
        else:
            muhtar = False
        if username == "" or password == "" or tc == "" or email == "":
            return render(request, "register.html", {"error": "Lütfen tüm alanları doldurun."})
        #elif len(tc) != 11:
        #    return render(request, "register.html", {"error": "TC kimlik numarası 11 haneli olmalıdır."})
        elif User.objects.filter(tc=tc).exists() or User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            return render(request, "register.html", {"error": "Bu kimlik numarası veya e-posta adresi zaten kullanılıyor."})
        else:
            user=User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password, tc=tc, muhtar=muhtar)
            user.save()
            return redirect("login")
    return render(request, "register.html")

def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        tc = request.POST.get("tc-no")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        if tc == "" or password == "" or email == "":
            return render(request, "login.html", {"error": "Lütfen tüm alanları doldurun."})
        user = authenticate(tc=tc, password=password, email=email)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("index")
        else:
            print(f"""
***************
TC: {tc}
Şifre: {password}
E-posta: {email}
***************""")
            return render(request, "login.html", {"error": "E-posta, T.C. veya şifre hatalı."})
    return render(request, "login.html")

def logoutPage(request):
    logout(request)
    return render(request, 'logout.html')

def profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated == False:
        return redirect("register")
    else:
        user = User.objects.get(tc=request.user.tc)
        return render(request, "profile.html", {"user": user})

def sos(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated == False:
        return redirect("register")
    elif not request.user.muhtar:
        return render(request, "harita.html", {"error": "Yardım çağırma yetkiniz yok."})

    if request.method == "POST":
        malzemeler = request.POST.get("exampleFormControlTextarea1")
        
        if not malzemeler:
            return render(request, "sos.html", {"fillError": "Lütfen gerekli alanları doldurun."})
        
        # Kullanıcının adresini ve usernamesini alabilirsiniz, örneğin:
        adres = request.user.address
        username = request.user.username
        
        # İşlemlerinizi yapabilirsiniz, örneğin bu bilgileri bir veritabanına kaydedebilirsiniz.
        
        # Başarılı bir şekilde işlem yapıldığında kullanıcıya bir mesaj göndermek için
        return render(request, "sos.html", {"succmsg": "Yardım çağrınız başarıyla gönderildi."})
    
    return render(request, "sos.html")
```

login.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Giriş Sayfası</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'libs/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'register_and_login.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'libs/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    {% block navbar %}
        {% include "navbar.html" %}
    {% endblock navbar %}
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <div id="brs">
            <br><br><br><br>
        </div>
        <!--giriş formu-->
        <form id="giris-form" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if error %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error }}</div>
            {% endif %}
            <h3>Giriş Yap</h3>

            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email">

            <label for="tc-no">T.C. no</label>
            <input type="text" id="tc-no" name="tc-no">

            <label for="parola">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="parola" name="password">

            <button type="submit" id="giris-yap">Giriş Yap</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please forgive my ignorance. I am new at django.

I wanted the user to log in, but authenticate() always returns None, even though my information is absolutely correct.